# Replacing a string in place

Tags: java, string, reverse

I am having an issue with a problem from my Intro Java class and this problem is a bit more than I can wrap my head around.

The problem is asking for a user to enter in a string and output the same string reversed in place

Example input: " How are you doing today? "
Example output : " today? doing you are How "

I am at a loss and not even sure how to start solving this problem...any tips would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried reversing string but it just reads backwards.

```
package reverseinplace;

import java.util.*;

public class ReverseInPlace {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String original, reverse = "";
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string to reverse");
        original = in.nextLine();
        int length = original.length();
        for ( int i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
            reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);
        System.out.println("Reverse of entered string is: "+reverse); 
   }
```

}

Should i use some sort of an array?
Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Tip: [`input.split(" ");`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: It might be a trick question; Java strings are immutable so you can't change them "in place".

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the String API. You can use the `split()` method to get an array of all the words.

Then you can iterate through the array in reverse order to recreate a new String with the words in reverse order.

You would probably want to use the `StringBuilder` class to create your new string.

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "How are you doing today?";
String[] inputAsArray = input.split(" ");
Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(inputAsArray));
String output="";
    for (String inputAsArray1 : inputAsArray) {
        output+=inputAsArray1+" ";
    }
```

If word delimiter is a space or tab. You have to import Collections and Arrays classes.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I took a look at several approaches provided and combined together with something of my own.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the input. I messed around a bit and got something like this as part of my own solution and it does the trick.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ReverseInPlace {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      String original, reverse = "";
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter a string to reverse");
      original = in.nextLine();
      String[] words = original.split("\\s+");
      System.out.print ("Reversed String in Place:" + " ");
      for (int i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ){
          System.out.print (words[i] + " ");
      }   
    }
}
```